# Components. Send request with file via vue.http.post()

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource, vue-component

I have vuejs2 component on page (single file component). It's a simple bootstrap modal window with one file input. I only need to upload one file (no mutlifile upload or etc.)

What is in file:

```
<template>
<div class="modal fade" id="upload-file-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload file</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="app-file-upload-form" name="appFileUploadForm" @submit.prevent="uploadAppFile" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="app-file-fileinput">File</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="app-file-fileinput" class="form-control" v-el="file" @change="attachFile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            file: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        attachFile(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

            if (!files.length)
                return;

            this.file = files[0];
        },

        uploadAppFile() {
            console.log(this.file);
            Vue.http.post('/api/v1/apps/' + this.appId + '/files', { file: this.file}).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }, (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So i have laravel controller for handle it.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $attachedFile = $request->file;

    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

I put return response->json() for kinda debug this. When i attach file, file attaching to component(model?) field and not empty. But when vue.http.post happening the file comes to empty object.

First is console.log(file)
Second is server response.

[image: chrome console]

I also tried with FormData()... it didn't work.
ps: i cut version field from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few more times with formdata i got file upload working. Just put variable inside method.

```
uploadAppFile() {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.file);

    Vue.http.post('/api/v1/apps/' + this.appId + '/files', data).then((response) => {});
}
```